# Get default argument value from a function call c++

Tags: c++

Code will probably better explain my problem better than words:

```
#include <string>

struct Something {};

struct Context
{
    std::string GetUniqueInentifier()
    {
        return "";
    }


    // ERROR
    void Register(const Something& something, const std::string& key = GetUniqueInentifier())
    {

    }
};

int main()
{
    Context c;
    c.Register(Something{}); //<- want to be able to do this 
                                // and a unique identifier will
                                // be automatically assigned 

    c.Register(Something{}, "Some Key"); //<- want to be able to let the user
                                            //  pick an identifier if they want
}
```

That is clearly not allowed but how can I simulate this behaviour ?

Comment: This is easily done with overloaded functions.

Comment: Ohh sorry, my function was in a class in my original case. Wait let me edit the question

Comment: Your problem will easily disappear if you stop using default arguments and use overloads. Default arguments are poor practice.

Comment: Yup, looks like I will have to use overload if this isn't possible. I am not used to them, I come from python haha

Comment: You can't use `this` in default arguments. There is no object (yet). Make the function `static`?

Comment: @Taekann default arguments are certainly NOT poor practice.

Comment: @TedLyngmo Ohhh. That does make sense. Thanks

Comment: @MichaelChourdakis they are, actually. They make your code objectively worse by multiple metrics. If there wasn’t an alternative to default arguments, that would be one thing, but overloading does everything they do, but better.

Comment: @Taekahn: default arguments have several drawback/pitfalls, we agree; Overloads doesn't solve all issues. in non-problematic cases, default arguments is less verbose.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use non-`static` member functions or variables as a default value to member functions.
Since the value returned by `GetUniqueInentifier()` doesn't require an instance of `Context`, make it `static` and you can then use it as you tried using it.

```
static std::string GetUniqueInentifier()
{
    return "";
}
```